# How to access the code behind click event code from a modal dialog box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog box which is a feedback form, on clicking the send button the code which has been written behind the page should execute. How to interconnect .

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is the jQuery dialog funciton moves the dialog elements outside of the web pages server form. To get around this you will have to append the dialog back to the form.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dlg = $('#popout').dialog();
            dlg.parent().appendTo($('form'));

        });
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#popout').dialog({
               open: function(type, data) {
                         $(this).parent().appendTo($('form'));
               }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: The modal windows will have the content of the div element which is available within the page. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: One clarification. Can you justify what does the 'form' means.

Comment: @Lokesh - the form in this case is the `<form>` page element. As this is a web page this should only have one form element which should have the runat='server' attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to assign event handlers. Here's an example:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="Button1_Click" ... />
```

In the above example, the `OnClick` attribute tells the button which code-behind event to use when the button is clicked:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your click event logic here
}
```